# asp net core create own generated migrations like rails

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a method to create migration in the asp net project manually? Generate empty migration file and add code that will change the database structure?

In the asp net core:

1. change the model

   ```
   class Product
   {
       public string PartNumber { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration -> it will inspect the model and generates the migration automatically.

In Ruby on Rails

1. rails generate migration MyMigration
2. write the migration

   ```
   class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
       def up
           add_column :products, :part_number, :string
       end
   end
   ```

I prefer the Rails way...

Comment: You can still modify the migration generated by ef migrations add command. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to use migrations but I would like to write all migrations myself without EF automatic inspecting of the model classes.